# How to increase paged pool memory?

Tags: 16.04, ram

Whenever I launch a game in steam, after a level or two, the game will crash with an error that says:

```
Failed to lock index "buffer in CMeshDX8::LockIndexBuffer"
```

Is there a way to allocate more memory to this?
I've got a lenovo Ideapad with 8GB of RAM and and Intel Core i3.

Here is my swapon:

[image]

Comment: What is your swap file partition size set to? In terminal, please type "swapon" and give us the results.

Comment: It says I have plenty of RAM, the game I play only requires 510MB, so I do not understand why I keep getting this error.

Comment: I'm guessing that it has to do with your video driver, or video settings. Do you know what video card you have, and what driver? Also, if you Google the entire error string, you'll come up with a lot of hits in the Steam forum, and even some in the Ubuntu forums. Take a look.